# Shopify Theme - theme style settings not in settings_schema.json file?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

does anyone know how to remove the "theme style" settings under a Shopify stores general Theme Settings? I do not see these settings defined anywhere inside the settings_schema.json file. Thanks in advance[image: Theme Settings Pic]

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if you are using the default Shopify theme called `debut` or any 3rd party theme that has the same settings into the backend customizer.

These settings are basically due to JSON code for presets for active theme inside the file called `settings_data.json` under `config` folder.
[image]

you need to just remove the code into `presets` to remove it. if you need it, by default it is not suggested to remove it.
[image]

Remove the highlighted part from the file and save it. and reload the customizer screen and it has gone.